# DESCRIBE TABLE in databricks piped into dataframe

Tags: databricks

Does anyone know of a method to pipe the "DESCRIBE TABLE" output in databricks into dataframe? (or other usable format which could be used for further analysis/computation)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

this method worked

```
dfAdbTableDescription = spark.sql("DESCRIBE TABLE "+dbutils.widgets.get("ADB_TABLE_PARM"))
adbTempTableName = "AdbTableDescription"
print("Description for ADB table "+dbutils.widgets.get("ADB_TABLE_PARM")+" is stored in a temp ADB table called...: " + adbTempTableName)
dfAdbTableDescription.createOrReplaceTempView(adbTempTableName);
dfAdbTableDescription.show(n=dfAdbTableDescription.count(), truncate=False, vertical=False)
```